# can I use a downloaded font asset in an iOS app?

Tags: ios

I want to use fonts in my app that I've downloaded from my server.  I may have a font at some point that I haven't bundled with the app but I want to use; is there a way to download it (well, that's the easy part) and then load it and use it in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an old question, but things are changed. The answer is yes since iOS 6.

Here is Apple's example:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to "notify" your app about which fonts you intend to use by adding them to the "Fonts Provided By Application" entry in your info.plist file. It is bad practice and for all intents-and-purposes wrong to edit this file at run time. Thus, all fonts that your app will use need to bundled with it at compile time and shipped along with the application.

Answer (score 0):

No, fonts have to be in your application bundle and registered with your Info.plist at compile-time.

If you really wanted to use a font that you downloaded, you could try converting it to a series of images and compositing them together, but that would be pretty hacky.